# How to add field to each object in Javascript array without loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, functional-programming

Is there a way to add a field to each object of a Javascript array without looping over it?

something like

```
array.each(function (index, object){
  object[newField] = anotherArray[index];
});
```

Comment: Just curious about why not loop? Cost too much?

Comment: are you sure its like function[newField] ?

Comment: in jquery you can use `jQuery.each`

Comment: @osrpt I want to use elements of functional programming where possible and was just wondering about the possibilities to do this in javascript.

Comment: I would say array.forEach (map, sum etc) is the functional programming alternative to classic looping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in the differences between an Object ({}) and an Array ([]).

Currently, a cached length loop offers the best performance for an Array.

But Array also offers a method `forEach`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach